# How to save value when onPress menu in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native and i'm testing how to save value when clicking button, here is the menu with two buttons

```
<MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Menu item 1</MenuItem>
<MenuItem onPress={this.printValue}>Menu item 2</MenuItem>
```

The followings lines are in my main activity

```
_storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('test', 'I like to save it.');
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
};

_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('test');
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
};

hideMenu = () => {
  this._storeData();
  this._menu.hide();
};

printValue = () => {
    this._retrieveData();
    alert(this._retrieveData.value);
}
```

The above code didn't work, anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a good attempt but you are missing a couple of things.

You should have `await` in front of your function calls as they are asynchronous functions. Also you are not returning anything from your `_retrieveData` function.

1. Add `await` in the correct places
2. Return the `value` from `_retrieveData` function, you may wish to return different values based on what you get back. You could refactor this to use a promise.

Here is your code with the updates to it.

```
_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('test');
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
      return value; // <- return the value that you have found
    }
     // you may wish to return something if no value is found
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
    // you may wish to return something if an error occurs
  }
};

hideMenu = () => {
  await this._storeData();  // <- add await here
  this._menu.hide();
};

printValue = () => {
    let value = await this._retrieveData(); // <- add await and capture the returned value
    alert(value);
}
```

Comment: I have this error for trying your answer "await is a reserved word" at await this._storeData();

Comment: After i added async to hideMenu, the problem was fixed